# How to build this a regex match in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
[X=(any number)] (any character, include space) [/X]
```

Example: [X=5]Test string[/X]

I test with `/(\[)(X=)(\d+\])(\w\s\.)(\[/X\])/gi` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the string? Extract information? Validated it? Something else?

Comment: It's good that there is *a* start. Consider breaking it down into pieces to find out *which* part doesn't work, however... this is part of debugging :) (This is easy to do in the REPL and there are online-regex validators, which are even simpler to use.)

Comment: @Louis.CLast. Replace what? validate what?

Comment: Ok, now i can do it work :D with /\[X=(\d+)\]([\w\s\.\-]+)\[\/X\]/gi

Comment: @Louis.CLast: Are you sure you don't want to escape the `[`s / `]`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `/` needs to be escaped as well. Also it's not very useful to group constant matches. Lastly, you're matching `(\w\s.)` but this only allows one word character, one space character and one character of any type, in this order. I don't see what's the use of that. Try:

```
/\[X=(\d+)\](.+)\[\/X\]/gi
```

This will group the two variable parts.

Comment: I think you need to replace `.*` with `.+`.

Comment: @gdoron: I can't quite make that up from the question, but it may be the case.

Comment: he has suggested to me \w and \s, and (. +), So I can be more easily understood. ([\w\s\.\-]+)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myregexp = /\[X=(\d+)\]([^[]*)\[\/X\]/g;
```

works for me, including if test string is multi-lines. Tested with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)

Answer (score 1):

Use this `regex`:

```
/\[X=\d+\].+\[\/X\]/gi
```

**It  checks if the given string is in the desired format.**

Comment: **Why are you shouting?** :-)